# java 8 stream transform list of maps to one single map. Cannot be cast to integer exception

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

The following code is a java 8 stream expected to transform list of maps to one map containing all the elements from this list of maps.. The test data below is throwing a cannot be cast to integer exception.

```
Map test = new HashMap();
test.put("PreLoadTransactionId", 1234);
List<Map<String, String>> preloadTranactions = new List<>();
preloadTranactions.add(test);
final Map<String, Date> preloadTranactionIdUpdateMap = preloadTranactions.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        preloadTransaction -> preloadTransaction.get("PreLoadTransactionId"),
        preloadTransaction -> new Date(preloadTransaction.get("UpdateDate")),
        (preloadTranaction1, preloadTranaction1Dup) -> preloadTranaction1));
```

Expecting to transform a list maps into a Map containing all the elements from this list of maps. Instead getting exception: "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String"

How am I getting this exception ???

Comment: Cannot replicate. Only posted error is `List<Map<String, String>> preloadTranactions = new List<>();` should be `List<Map<String, String>> preloadTranactions = new ArrayList<>();` - there are quite a few warnings. Why are you using `Date(String)`?

Comment: using Date(String) because the input is a date string..

Answer (score 2):

First of all we do not know from this code snippet what is the type of "PreLoadTransactionId" and "UpdateDate" fields in the map.

If any of them is Integer you will get this error.
You should check how the map of preloadTransactions is being populated.
This when it is defined like `Map<String, String>` doesn't mean anything since in the example here:

```
List<Map<String, String>> preloadTranactions = new ArrayList<>();
    Map test = new HashMap();
    test.put("PreLoadTransactionId", 1234);
    preloadTranactions.add(test);
```

You could save integer as a transactionId even it is declared in preloadTranactions as a Map with String values

So I think you just need to see how the map is populated and to fix the population or to explicitly cast to String in your Collector like this:

```
preloadTranactions.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                preloadTransaction -> 
                String.valueOf( //THIS WILL FIX THE ISSUE EVEN IF VALUE IS NUMBER
                    preloadTransaction.get("PreLoadTransactionId")
                ),
                preloadTransaction -> new Date(preloadTransaction.get("UpdateDate")),
                (preloadTranaction1, preloadTranaction1Dup) -> preloadTranaction1));
```

Comment: Yes you are right that worked for me. Still puzzles me why it doesn't throw a exception when you put a integer and the defined type is String...